# Get DbContext in async action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am rewriting/ moving a website from ASP MVC to ASP MVC Core. This application has a dynamic menu which depends on the logged in user. In order to build the menu, each  controller derives from a custom `BaseController` who sets in `ViewBag` menu items, an later, in Layout, those items are retrieved and passed as arguments to a `PartialView`.

```cs
public BaseController:Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
          ...
          ViewBag.Menu=Utils.GetMenu();
          ...
    }
}
```

I don't want to use the same logic as the lads who wrote the old code. So I thought to use a `ViewComponent` to render the menu. But I have a problem with this approach. In Invoke method I need to query for the menu items. Right now I get a DbContext instance from the service provider (`HttpContext.RequestServices`), and I use it to query whatever data I need. But the Invoke function is called asynchronously from `Layout` and I know that it is not very good to send DbContext to `async` methods:

```
<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromHours(2)" enabled="true">
       @await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(Admin.ViewComponents.MeniuViewComponent))
</cache>
```

Is this a good approach? Is it safe to get a DbContext (registered as Scoped in Startup) in Invoke method (or any other `async` method or action) and use it? And if it is not a good idea, how should I deal with this kind of situations where I need data from db in `async` methods?

Comment: It looks like you don't separate your representation layer from the data layer. Do you have Repositories to manipulate DB data and Services to handle some business logic? It's a common approach to not do any kind of db calls inside of the view. You have to prepare all data and send it inside the view you have.

Comment: Yes, I have. But in repository i try to fetch data from cache ( I use MemoryCache) and if it is a miss, i fetch them from DB. Anyway, aren't viewcomponents supposed to provide action-style support ? I'm not trying to fetch data from View, I try to fetch it from Invoke function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the case in my project to get the DbContext inside a HostedService from asp.net core.

I injected the IServiceProvider inside the constructor and build my own scope, to get the registered DbContext:

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
public BaseController(IServiceProvider provider){
  _serviceProvider = provider;
}

private void DoSth(){
  using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
  var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YOUR_DbContext_CLASS>();

  ... //do something great stuff here with the database
}
```

Comment: you need to wrap `scope` variable in the `using` clause. otherwise your db context won't be disposed

Comment: @YegorAndrosov thank you for your hint you are absolutly right. It's an typo/copypaste error, as I use the scope variable with using to get it disposed at the end

Comment: @DannySchneider thanks ! So whenever i deal with functions that can be called asynchronuous I should create a new dbcontext?

Comment: I think it depends, try to figure out your scope lifetime and where inside the request lifecycle your DB context is needed. A scoped registered class becomes instantiated once in a single request lifecycle. If the scope is not disposed before you use it, the way from @mj1313 suites best, I think...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly dependency inject the DbContext in the ViewComponent

```
public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly MenuDbContext _context;

    public TopMenuViewComponent(MenuDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var model = _context.MenuItems.ToList();

        return View("Default", model);
    }
}
```

For more details, refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-a-viewcomponent-class).

Comment: Yes I know I can get it this way. But the injected dbcontext is shared in this case across all methods called during request. Is it safe to work with this shared dbcontext?